# Frequent rebalancing of Apache Kafka freezes the operation for the duration of the rebalancing

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-dotnet

When sending a message to Kafka there is a rebalancing that freezes the process of Kafka for a time equal to the balancing, there are logs in which the error is indicated. How to fix it?

```
[2023-09-25 14:46:05,115] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Dynamic member with unknown member id joins group 0 in Stable state. Created a new member id rdkafka-5fc941fc-e214-498e-af7a-8d56ee5f37b3 and request the member to rejoin with this id. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2023-09-25 14:46:05,117] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Preparing to rebalance group 0 in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 865 (__consumer_offsets-48) (reason: Adding new member rdkafka-5fc941fc-e214-498e-af7a-8d56ee5f37b3 with group instance id None; client reason: not provided) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2023-09-25 14:46:38,151] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Member rdkafka-4cf658bc-60b2-44df-8121-eca7900b9287 in group 0 has failed, removing it from the group (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2023-09-25 14:46:38,153] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Stabilized group 0 generation 866 (__consumer_offsets-48) with 3 members (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2023-09-25 14:46:38,157] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Assignment received from leader rdkafka-658c3410-e10c-42dd-b67d-cbde581af7d7 for group 0 for generation 866. The group has 3 members, 0 of which are static. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
```

Here is my Consumer code:

```
public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Consumer started!");
        
        var config = new ConsumerConfig
        {
            BootstrapServers = "***",
            GroupId = "0",
            AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest,
            ClientId = "consumer 1",
            EnableAutoCommit = true,
            EnableAutoOffsetStore = false
        };
        
        using (_consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(config)
                   .SetPartitionsRevokedHandler((c, partitions) =>
                   {
                   })
                   .Build())
        {
            SubscribeConsumer(_consumingTopic);
            
            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var consumeResult = _consumer.Consume(cancellationToken);

                _consumerHandler.HandleResult(consumeResult);
                _consumer.StoreOffset(consumeResult);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Consumer close!");
            _consumer.Close();
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Comment: Producers don't cause rebalancing. Can you share your consumer code?

Comment: Thank! Added the consumer code

Comment: What is `_consumerHandler.HandleResult`? How are long does this take? Kafka will rebalance a group if record processing takes too long

Comment: This handler processes the message and sends records to the database, this happens instantly without delay. At the moment I came to the following - I divided all consumers into unique consumer groups and judging by Kafka's logs rebalancing doesn't happen anymore. I have 3 consumers working for each of the 3 tops. Each consumer I defined its own Client Id and made manual saving of offsets. This all helped me to solve the problem! By the way, the problem I'm facing is called "Stop-The-World".

Comment: Number of consumers should match number of partitions, by the way

Answer (score 1):

I divided all consumers into unique consumer groups and judging by Kafka's logs rebalancing doesn't happen anymore. I have 3 consumers working for each of the 3 tops. Each consumer I defined its own Client Id and made manual saving of offsets. This all helped me to solve the problem! By the way, the problem I'm facing is called "Stop-The-World".